# How to use OrientDB over HTTPS?

Tags: java, php, orientdb

I have [OrientDB](https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb) 1.6.3 and 1.6.4 servers running on my local development machine. The client has required https: protocol to access [OrientDB's REST interface](https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb/wiki/OrientDB-REST).

I have been unable to locate the configuration settings to enable the https engine in the java embedded http server. Can someone point me to them?

Alternately, what is another way to use https connections to the [OrientDB REST interface](https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb/wiki/OrientDB-REST)?

The data access will need to be [HIPAA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Health_Insurance_Portability_and_Accountability_Act) compliant.

Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried accessing the api with https:// their documents claim they have builtin support for https

Comment: @yazanjaber Yes, timeout on port 2480 using https, works using http. Failed when using 'https' in place of http in the orientdb-server-config.xml config file.

Comment: I miss read your last comment though  I still think you should try to use the default https port maybe the port range in the config is not taken into account when using https.

Answer (score 1):

OrientDB doesn't support HTTPS out of the box, you should put Apache or any other layer in front of it.

Comment: Apache is not currently available on the host. I was also thinking about establishing a SSH tunnel, but OpenSSH is not available. I may need to request the client add more host services. Any links showing https: to Apache, redirected to OrientDB:2480 and back? I may be able to get Apache installed.

Comment: I've tried with Apache reverse-proxy mod and works perfectly.

Comment: Let me try that and I'll get back.

Comment: Any https support in upcoming 1.7 Release